# Web scraping em página com login e senha

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Estou tentando extrair um código fonte de um arquivo html com o seguinte estilo:

```
 <div class="both"></div>
    <div class="st-box" id="source-code">
        <h3>SOURCE CODE</h3>

        <div class="wrap code-answer-1">

            <pre id="code" class="code-2">#include &lt;bits/stdc++.h&gt;

        using namespace std;

        int main ()
        {
            double A, B, C;

            scanf (&quot;%lf %lf %lf&quot;, &amp;A, &amp;B, &amp;C);
            printf (&quot;TRIANGULO: %.3lf\n&quot;, (A * C) / 2.0);
            printf (&quot;CIRCULO: %.3lf\n&quot;, C * C * 3.14159);
            printf (&quot;TRAPEZIO: %.3lf\n&quot;, ((A + B) * C) / 2.0);
            printf (&quot;QUADRADO: %.3lf\n&quot;, B * B);
            printf (&quot;RETANGULO: %.3lf\n&quot;, A * B);
            system (&quot;pause&quot;);
            return 0;
        }</pre>

                </div>
            </div>

                </ul>
        </div>
```

Utilizando o seguinte código:

```
 def getCode(self, id):
    return self.getPage('https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/'+self.lang+'/runs/code/'+id).find("pre ", {"id": "code"}).text
```

Entretanto recebo o seguinte erro:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Como resolver?

Comment: Você esqueceu de colocar o erro completo. Se o erro é mesmo nessa linha, significa que ele não achou o elemento `<pre id="code">` nesse html.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema? Ainda tem alguma dúvida?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, você inseriu um espaço depois de `pre`:

> [...].find(***"pre "***, {"id": "code"}).text

Corrigindo o código e removendo esse espaço, conforme abaixo o erro deveria ser sanado:

```
def getCode(self, id):
    return self.getPage('https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/'+self.lang+'/runs/code/'+id).find("pre", {"id": "code"}).text
```

Mas, no entanto, esse site possui login e você só pode acessar os `id` referentes ao seu usuário. Abaixo fiz um código que você pode implementar na sua função para ter o que busca:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import http.cookiejar as cookielib

cookies = cookielib.CookieJar()  # cria um repositório de cookies
browser = mechanize.Browser()    # inicia um browser
browser.set_cookiejar(cookies)   # aponta para o seu repositório de cookies

# substitua 'seu_id' por um id válido que você tenha acesso
browser.open('https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/runs/code/seu_id')

browser.select_form(nr=0)      # o formulário de senha é o primeiro
browser.form['email'] = 'seu_emaik'     # substitua 'seu_email' pelo seu e-mail
browser.form['password'] = 'senha'  # substitua 'senha' pela sua senha
browser.submit()               # submissão dos dados

pagina = browser.response().read()  # essa é a página que você queria 

# Beautiful Soup aqui
soup = bs(pagina,'html.parser')
codigo = soup.find("pre",{"id":"code"}).text

print(codigo) # o dado que você buscava
```

Comment: Eu tentei tirando o espaço e o erro foi o mesmo

Comment: Fiz uma edição da resposta porque vi que a página que você tenta acessar carece de login e senha. Tente agora e se der erro, tente ser mais claro mostrando a implementação que você fez e o erro em si para que seja possível simular o que você construiu.